# Fql request error?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-fql

```
    String fqlurl="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?SELECT flid, owner, name friendlist WHERE owner=me()&format=json";
```

I made request but I don't see the result I have an error 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query 
What's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify `FROM` ex:

```
 SELECT flid, owner, name FROM friendlist WHERE owner=me()
```